# How do I change NS records to my web host without breaking already set up email functionality with another host?

Tags: dns, domain-registration

I bought 2 domains managed by Google Domains, the .CA and the .COM versions. Let's call them `example.ca` and `example.com`

I purchased GSuite for business for this domain and created a personal email, `byron@example.com`

I purchased a hosting plan from a third-party provider called HostPapa.

The issue:

To set up my website, I need to set up my name servers to point to the HostPapa servers, but doing so causes my Gsuite email to be unable to receive mail.

The Question:

What do I need to set up so that I can have my email and domain hosted by Google and working properly, but still have the `example.com` and `example.ca` point to my website at HostPapa?

Comment: "To set up my website, I need to set up my name servers to point to" - you didn't necessarily need to change the NS records. You could have instead created `A` (and optionally `CNAME`) records to point to the web host, and keep everything else the same. https://www.hostpapa.co.uk/knowledgebase/servers-ip-address/

Comment: Isn't this one of the reasons that most URLs used to begin with "www."?

Answer (score 1):

You point the MX records to gsuite

```
1   ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM.
5   ALT1.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM.
5   ALT2.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM.
10  ALT3.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM.
10  ALT4.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM.
```